In C programming language, can the main function begin with main() instead of int main()?
I'm reading the "C Programming Language, 2nd edition" by Dennis Ritchie and Brian W.Kernighan. On page 38, the main body of the program begins with main() instead of int main(), I believe that's an error. But I'm a novice programmer. Are there any special conditions or cases for which you doesn't have to mention the type int in front of the main function?
I tried without mentioning int and the compiler didn't execute.

That book is old and does not follow modern standard. The main function must be declared to have an explicit int return type.

Even int main() isn't quite right. You need to specify what its parameters are, e.g. int main(void).

The second edition was published just before C90 was finalized.  In deference to the existing code base (large), C90 allowed main() instead of int main(void) etc.  C99 officially removed support for that.  K&R was a great book in its time (the 1st Edn, from 1978, especially so). The world has moved on since then, and C has evolved and there are a number of parts of K&R 2 that no longer compile or work reliably. That makes it a less satisfactory introductory text now.  It hurts me to say that. I learned C from 1st Edn and have a copy of 2nd Edn — I have a high regard for both of them.  But…

@pmacfarlane: the C18 and earlier standards show examples of int main().  It is not incorrect — but it doesn't provide a prototype for main(), any more than int function(); provides a prototype.  It's a declaration of function, but the argument list is indeterminate (but is not a variadic function — its definition signature does not end with , ...) ).  C23 changes all that.  Using int function(); in C23 is equivalent to int function(void); — and is a prototype for the function.  That is likely to cause problems for older code.  Don't get me wrong: I prefer int main(void), but …

https://godbolt.org/z/6x4q39fhG <- you can ask the compiler to use the c90 standard, which should allow the code to compile; but a better idea would be to find a more recent book. The K+R book is a classic, but the language has evolved somewhat in the decades since.

@pmacfarlane For a function definition, an empty parameter type list is equivalent to a parameter type list of void. For a function declaration, an empty parameter type list declares the function to have unknown parameters (pre-C23) or no parameters (post-C23).

K&R wasn't even correct for C89, because every example in the book invokes UB when used on for example Unix, which is a system that uses the value returned from main(). Related: Have the code examples from K&R ever been conforming? The book is not just outdated - the 2nd edition was never correct to begin with.

The earliest versions of C (up to C99) allowed an "implicit int" definition; functions that didn't have an explicit type were assumed to return int.  K&R C didn't even have function prototype syntax, so function definitions with parameters looked like this:
/**  
 * Return type is assumed to be int
 *
 * Parameter list only contains the names of the parameters;
 * types must be specified in a separate declaration
 */
foo(x, y) 
  int x;
  int y;
{
  return x*y;
}

So yeah, in a lot of very old C code (1970s through the late 1980s), you'll see main defined as
main()
{
  ...
}

or
main(argc, argv)
  int argc;
  char **argv;
{
  ...
}

Practice since C89 is to use prototype syntax, and again implicit int is no longer allowed since C99, so main should be defined as
int main( void )
{
  ...
}

or
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  ...
}


You are right! But I'm little confused, why should you explicitly declare int in front of main? While you don't have to specify the data type for other functions. Let's say I'm calling foo(); After all, even int main() is a function.

@Greeshma: Since C99, all functions, including main, must have an explicit type specification.  Implicit typing is no longer allowed anywhere.
